# How do I get Jest to recognise JQuery in my Rails project?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, jestjs, sprockets, webpacker

I'm working on an originally-Rails-4-now-upgraded-to-5.1.6.2 app.

We originally relied on Sprockets for our JS, but have now mostly migrated to Webpacker, and for which I want to start introducing Jest tests.

We still have a residual Sprockets presence in `application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require select2
//= require icheck.min
//= require jquery.Jcrop.min
```

And in our Gemfile we require `gem "jquery-rails", "~> 4.3.3"`

Having recently started integrating some Vue components to the project, I want to eventually be able to test Vue components, but since I don't feel like I understand them as well as I'd like, I started out trying to test the following 'simple' bit of JQuery dom manipulation:

```
// PledgeFormUpdates.js

export default function() {
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    if ( $('#pledge-form').length == 0 ) {
      return;
    }

    // Determine whether to show GDPR checkbox on country change
    $("#pledge_pledgor_home_country").change(function() {
      let gdpr_form_group = $("#js-gdpr-input");
      let checkbox = $('#pledge_receive_comms')
      const eu_countries = [
        "Austria",
        "Belgium",
        "Bulgaria",
        "Croatia",
        "Cyprus",
        "Czech Republic",
        "Denmark",
        "Estonia",
        "Finland",
        "France",
        "Germany",
        "Greece",
        "Hungary",
        "Ireland",
        "Italy",
        "Latvia",
        "Lithuania",
        "Luxembourg",
        "Malta",
        "Netherlands",
        "Poland",
        "Portugal",
        "Romania",
        "Slovakia",
        "Slovenia",
        "Spain",
        "Sweden",
        "United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland"
      ]

      if ( eu_countries.includes(this.value) ) {
        checkbox.prop('disabled', false);
        gdpr_form_group.show();
      } else {
        checkbox.prop('disabled', true);
        gdpr_form_group.hide();
      };
    });
  });
}
```

The test file currently has this content:

```
'use strict';

import pledge_form_updates from '../../app/javascript/components/PledgeFormUpdates.js'

test('Displays GDPR checkbox on EU country selection', () => {
  // Set up our document body
  document.body.innerHTML =
    '<select id="pledge_pledgor_home_country">' +
    '  <option value="Brazil" selected>Brazil</option>'
    '  <option value="Germany">Germany</option>' +
    '  <button id="button" />' +
    '</select>';
});
```

Our package.json includes the following config:

```
{
  // ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "jest": {
    "roots": [
      "spec/javascript"
    ],
    "setupFiles": ["./spec/javascript/setup-jest.js"]
  }
}
```

And lastly in the setup-jest.js file, we just attempt to import JQuery, based on suggestions I saw in posts like [this](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/679#issuecomment-311887619):

```
import $ from 'jquery/src/jquery';

// Other failed attempts:
// import $ from 'jquery';
// import $ from 'jquery/jquery';
global.$ = global.jQuery = $;
```

But all variations of this fail with some variation of the error `Cannot find module 'jquery/jquery' from 'setup-jest.js'`

So how can I successfully import JQuery for use in this kind of test?

ETA: Based on the comment below, in case relevant here's also the (now-amended) contents of the environment.js file:

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader')
const vue = require('./loaders/vue')

environment.plugins.prepend('VueLoaderPlugin', new VueLoaderPlugin())
environment.loaders.prepend('vue', vue)
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }))
module.exports = environment
```

Comment: Put this code in your environment.js file `environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery' 
}))` and change `import $ from 'jquery/src/jquery';` to `import $ from 'jquery';`.

Comment: I copied and pasted this, but the error is still the same: `Cannot find module 'jquery' from 'setup-jest.js'`

Answer (score 3):

Ok, the answer was Cannon Moyer's comment plus one step:

From the terminal, I needed to run `yarn add jquery`

Then in environment.js, I needed to add his code:

```
environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({ $: 'jquery', jQuery: 'jquery' }))
```

... and in setup-jest.js, to change `import $ from 'jquery/src/jquery';` to `import $ from 'jquery';`